# How to calculate how many times a function inside a for loop inside a while loop will be called?

Tags: complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, c

I'm studying for my exams and a came through this exercise but I can't prove the result I found.

Given this piece of code:

```c
int k = 0;
while (k < n/2) {
    for (int l=k+1; l<=n; l=l*2) {
        printf("\n");
    }
    k = k+2;
}
```

I am asked to calculate how many times `printf()` will be called.

I calculated by hand how many times it would be called for different values of `n` and found the following:

```
for n=2: it was called 2 times
n= 4:   3 times
n= 8:   6 times
n=16:  12 times
n=32:  24 times
n=64:  48 times
```

It seems to me like the function that would accept `n` as a parameter and return how many times `printf()` would run is:

`f(n) = round((3/4)*n)`

Is this the correct way to calculate how many times `printf()` will run based on the value of `n` or am I doing something wrong? Additionally what would be the correct way to justify my answer of how I calculated how many times it'll be called?

P.S. I've also calculated the `O()` complexity of the code above if that helps in any way.

Comment: Write down for which values k the inner loop iterates once, twice, three times and so on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a system behind the magic of algorithm analysis?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis)